# how to use variable in ng-click and ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I opened a ng-repeat block and I want to use "id" as counter for define toggle button  counter in ng-click like this:

my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="line in linesList">
   <a ng-click="'modal{{line.id}=!modal{{line.id}}'">{{line.id}}</>
</div>
```

my result is like this:

```
ng-click="'modal1=!modal1'"
```

but I need this:

```
ng-click="modal1=!modal1"
```

Comment: use a function in your controller instead and pass the id

Comment: Use an object or array instead of individual variable names! `modal[line.id]`…

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object 'modal', not multiple variables modal1, modal2, etc.

In your controller :

```
$scope.modal = {}
$scope.toggleModal = function(id) {
  $scope.modal[id] = !$scope.modal[id] 
}
```

And then:

```
<div ng-repeat="line in linesList">
   <a ng-click="toggleModal(line.id)">{{line.id}}</>
</div>
```

See example here : http://codepen.io/thierry36t/pen/QGqPyj

Comment: I tried it $scope.modal = ['modal1','modal2','modal3','modal4','modal5','modal6']; in my controller by my result is still wrong: ng-click="modal[line.id]=!modal[line.id]"

Comment: Great! Can you accept the answer if it helps you? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, Stackoverflow does not allow me to vote unfortunately